# Flutter Firebase push onLaunch called multiple times on app refresh

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

I'm facing an issue of getting called `onLaunch` method multiple times whenever I refresh the app.

I have found git issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32698)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the Firebase application and requestPermission egain.

In the bellow example i will pass the user to the on Launch:

```
onLaunch(User user) async {
  Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) async {
    try {
      value.delete(); // The default Firebase app instance cannot be deleted. but this will remove previous subscriptions.
    } catch (e) {}
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    String token = await messaging.getToken(); // get the token
    user.mobileId = token.toString();
    BackendRequester.registerPushClient(user); // send it to the backend

    messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((token) { // if token refreshed will notify the backend
      user.mobileId = token.toString();
      BackendRequester.registerPushClient(user);
    });
  });
}
```